# Is there an english translation of Manusmriti by Dr. Surendra Kumar available?

Tags: manu-smriti

As I understand Dr. Kumar has identified shlokas that are adulterated or interpolated, and he has accompanied it with an explanation. His work is on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/ManuSmritiByDrSurenderKumar/page/n343) but in Hindi. 50% of verses seem out of place - 1471 out of 2685 shlokas.

I could not find an english translation of his work. Has anyone gone through his work in Hindi ? Or better still is there an english translation available anywhere?